# Bloquear ENTER de un SPAN

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo el siguiente codigo en **html** para un **span** y un **input**. De forma sencilla, el **span** tiene una etiqueta "**contenteditable="true"**" que lo que hace es que pueda digitar en él, despues un **input**... su funcionalidad consiste en que si el codigo que dijito en el **span** existe en mi base de datos, cargue en el **input** el nombre de un cliente o una campaña, etc, al "**tabular**" o como tambien deberia servir al dar "**ENTER**"; el problema es que cuando digito el codigo y presiono **ENTER**, el **span** hace un **salto de linea**. Mi pregunta es, como podria hacer que en vez de que haga un **salto de linea**, haga un salto pero al siguiente campo(que seria el **input**)

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <label class="control-label">Ejemplo: </label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon buscar" id="id" tabindex="1" contenteditable="true" style="color:black;font-weight:bold">span</span>
    <input placeholder="input" class="form-control input-sm input-combi" id="nombre" name="nombre" readonly="" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Al verlo en el navegador y dar **ENTER** se muestran esos **br**

[image: Al verlo en el navegador y dar **ENTER** se muestran esos **<br>**]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo lo haría añadiendo un evento `keypress` al `span` en el cual controles qué tecla has pulsado. Si ha sido el enter `(keyCode: 13)` llamas a `preventDefault()` para evitar que se lance el evento y así no escribes el enter. Después harías lo que necesites hacer.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let span = document.getElementById("idSpan");  
  span.addEventListener("keypress",function(e){
    if(e.keyCode===13){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("He pulsado Enter pero no lo he escrito");
      //Aquí sigues haciendo lo que necesites
    }
});
};
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <label class="control-label">Ejemplo: </label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon buscar" id="idSpan" tabindex="1" contenteditable="true" style="color:black;font-weight:bold">span</span>
    <input placeholder="input" class="form-control input-sm input-combi" id="nombre" name="nombre" readonly="" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Kiko_L podria servír, lo voy probar

Comment: si me sirvió. muchas gracias kiko-l